# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable - Creating list

Tags: python, list

I have an issue with the following:

```
def list_func(list_ids):
    counter = 0
    for ids in list_ids:
        id = ids[counter]
```

The above gives the following error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. The `list_ids` value is [22], just one int.

I have also tried `id = int(ids[counter])` but that gives the same error. This looks like a simple fix, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: ids here is simply the value 22, so you are trying to get the "counter"th value from 22. you are already looping through list_ids with the for loop

Comment: @Marc Simple fix ... `id = ids` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `id = ids['id']` line. `ids[]` format for the index of an item you can't use it with item itself. For example if your `'id'`index is `2` you can use `id = ids[2]`. So you first find the index number of the `'id'` item.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect in your list_ids the elements are integers. Now in your forloop you iterate through these elements, so through the integers. The problem is that where say
id = ids[counter] because you can't ask for example the second element of an integer. An integer is not a list! If you want 'id' being the current integer of the list_ids where your forloop is, then use id = ids